# Conditional formatting in matrix cells

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

I have the following matrix loaded:

[image]

I need to change the font color of the BB column values ​​when the value is below the value contained in the MIN column cell.
Being grouped columns, the MIN column will not always be in fourth place. How can I do to compare values ​​taking into account the name of the columns?

Thank you!!

I share the output of the dataset:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample of the dataset output as that might make a difference to the answer.

Comment: I share the output of the dataset:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution based on our discussion in the comments:

- Create a calculated field in your dataset Ref = ELEMENT + COMPONENT (concatenate the 2 colums, this will be used later)
- In the **Row Group** properties, add a variable MinVar =lookup("MIN" & Fields!Component.Value ,Fields!Ref.Value,Fields!Value.Value,"DataSet1") (replace DataSet1 with your dataset name)
- In the font expression of the value field add an expression =if(Fields!Element.Value ="BB",if(Me.Value< Variables!MinVar.value,"Red","Black") ,"Black")

I have tested this and it is working on my end.

Comment: In the example above what would be the corresponding to "yourfieldname" and "yourdsname"?

Comment: The MIN field may have another name, perhaps ZZ. For the example, I want to put in red those values ​​of BB that are less than the values ​​of the MIN field.

Comment: MIN is the function for minimum not the value in your table, the yourdsname is the dataset name in your report builder (Dataset 1 if you havent renamed it) so the expression would be =if(Me.Value = MIN(Fields!Value.Value, "Dataset 1") ,"Red","Black")

Comment: So you can get the minimum value of the column but what I want is to compare 2 values ​​horizontally. In the example that I uploaded, only that value "3" is the one that meets the condition.

Comment: Since the "3" is less than "33" so I put it in red.

Comment: For the other registers "29" is not less than "20" so I set it to black.
"37" is not less than "11", so it also goes in black.

Comment: I have found a solution and edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you SamBouKoa! 
I'm going to try it

Comment: Is the expression correct: MinVar =lookup("MIN" & Fields!Component.Value ,Fields!Ref.Value,Fields!Value.Value,"DataSet1")? Could it be that the parameter before the name of Dataset1 is wrong?

Comment: This: Fields!Value.Value

Comment: this is correct assuming that the last column name in your dataset is called "Value" (as per the screenshot) if it has a different name it should be Fields!ColumnName.value

Comment: It doesn't change the color for me.

Comment: It works now. Since the "Element" field is defined as nchar(10), I changed the expression like this:  =if(Fields!Element.Value like "BB*",if(Me.Value< Variables!MinVar.value,"Red","Black") ,"Black")

Thank you very much SamBouKoa!!